# Get nested JSON values

Tags: c#, json

I send a request to an API and I get this JSON back:

```
{{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "LoginTest",
  "status": "ready",
  "testvalues_count": 2,
  "testvalues": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Username",
      "value": "Test"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Password",
      "value": "password1"
    }
  ]
}}
```

I can get the value of the `name` item easily:

```
var api = new DataApi();
var json = api.GetTestData("LoginTest");
dynamic testData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
var name = testData.name;
```

But I also need the values of the `Username` and `Password` items. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't use `dynamic`, every time you do a kitten dies. Instead use a proper class.

Comment: Also what you have given us isn't valid JSON, did you mean to surround it with extra `{...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class for your json by simply pasting your JSON object in the menu VS Edit/Special paste

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int testvalues_count { get; set; }
    public Testvalue[] testvalues { get; set; }
}

public class Testvalue
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
Rootobject testData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Comment: Instead of posting this, it would have been much better to point OP to the "Paste JSON as classes" option that you used here. Or point them at one of the the thousands of other "how do I parse JSON" questions.

Comment: Ah great! And how would getting that value than be? `testData.testvalues.name`?

Comment: @John  Almost, `testData.testvalues[index].name;` becuse is `testvalues` if of type `List`

Comment: @styx No, it is an array.